# Assembly Versioning on Legacy .Net Apps

Tags: asp.net, powershell

I got version of .Net Project on my IIS. For example; 3.10.5 etc. On my repository ı have new project which is "3.20.2" There are 17 projects differences between this project. How could i do it?

I mean there is newer version of this project in my gitlab(repository). I want to compare how many version differences between this project? I could not explain sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are 17 projects differences between this project

Except there aren't. Version numbers are in the format `major.minor.patch[.revision]`. One could go from `3.10.5` to `3.11.0` in one release, or from `3.10.5` to `3.10.347` if there are many bugs in `3.10.5`, and then go to `4.0` because they're done with the old codebase. As how many "differences" does that count?

If you really want to do math on version numbers, but you shouldn't, parse a `System.Version` and subtract the relevant properties.